# Can't install guzzlehttp for Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, guzzle

I am using PHP 5.4 and I have Laravel 5.1 for my development. When I try to install guzzlehttp through composer for my Laravel I get error that your PHP 5.4 doesn't specify the requirements. 
i tried to install it by lowering the version like

```
composer require "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "5.0"
```

but still with no luck.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try,

```
composer require "guzzlehttp/guzzle:~5.3"
```

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to track the development over at guzzle and select the version you need (or don't specify a version and get the latest).

Comment: To install globally: `composer global require guzzlehttp/guzzle`.